# How do I do an <i> tag within a link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to replicate this:

```
<a href="thepledge.html" class="btn btn-inverse btn-mini btn-ten"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Take The Pledge</a>
```

I tried this:

```
<%= link_to("Take the pledge", root_path, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-mini btn-ten")  do %>
   <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
<% end %>
```

But it gave me this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/":String
```

At the `link_to` call.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to(root_path, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-mini btn-ten") do %>
  <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
  Take The Pledge
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) you need to put the (complete) link text in the block, like this:

```
<%= link_to(root_path, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-mini btn-ten")  do %>
   <i class="icon-pencil">Take the pledge</i>
<% end %>
```